# Moving data from specific columns to a different column in a new row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv containing details of documents located on Google Drive. I am trying to make it easier to read and deal with as this example has over 400 columns.

Each row in the csv represents a file on Google drive. There are multiple columns to denote who owns the file and who it is shared with.

Every time a file has been shared, the details of the person it has been shared with are appended as a new column to that row.

I have loaded the data into Pandas data frame and I'm struggling to move the contents of certain columns to a new row.

Below is an example

```
Input:
owner  |  id  |  title | permissions.0.name | permissions.0.email | permsissions.1.name | permissions.1.email
value     1      doc1    Tommy                tommy@office.com      Timmy                 timmy@office.com
value     2      doc2    Tommy                tommy@office.com
value     3      doc3    Timmy                timmy@office.com
value     4      doc4    Tammy                tammy@office.com      Tommy                 tommy@office.com

Output:
owner  |  id  |  title | permissions.0.name | permissions.0.email 
value     1      doc1    Tommy                tommy@office.com      
value     2      doc2    Tommy                tommy@office.com
value     3      doc3    Timmy                timmy@office.com
value     4      doc4    Tammy                tammy@office.com      
value     5      doc1    Timmy                timmy@office.com
value     6      doc4    Tommy                tommy@office.com
```

I began by creating a list of and finding out the maximum number in the column headings (it is 46 in the full data). Then loop through from 1 to 46 building the column name to look at and moving the contents from that column to a different column on a new row. But I had no idea how to move the contents...

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv(input.csv)

cols = list(df) #list of column names

maxcol =[]

for c in cols:
    if '.' in c:
        n = c.split('.')[1]
        maxcol.append(int(n))

maxval = max(maxcol)

for i in range(1 to maxval):
    colname = 'permissions.' + str(i) + '.name'
    # move contents from this column to permissions.0.name in new row somehow
```

There are many more columns (over 400) and do not appear in an organised structure. For example columns are created when required. So we have columns like this:

```
permissions.5.email | permissions.1.withPhoto | permissions.6.name | permission.6.email
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. I think there are easier ways to do this, but it seems to be giving the required result:

```
cols = list(df)
# Get the variable column names
per_cols = [c for c in cols if '.' in c]
# Get the constant column names, i.e. title
main_cols = [c for c in cols if '.' not in c]
# Get the set of numbers present in columns
col_no = set([c.split('.')[1] for c in per_cols])

result = pd.DataFrame()
for col in col_no:
    # Get the list of columns with the current number
    part = [c for c in per_cols if c.split('.')[1] == col]
    # Add the constant columns to get a complete df
    part =  main_cols + part
    temp = df[part]
    # Change the name of columns to '0' for unified result
    temp.columns = [c.replace(col, '0') for c in temp.columns]
    # Drop the NaN rows (preferrably use a subset you are certain wouldn't be null)
    temp = temp.dropna()
    # Append the chunck of df to result
    # If the chunck has a new column, it will be added to result df
    result = result.append(temp)
```